# Grep return whole object instead of array

Tags: jquery, json, javascript-objects

Is there any way i can force grep function of jquery to return new object with reflected new array? For example I have sample JSON and javascript like below.

```
var myObject = {     "Apps" : [    
    {
        "Name" : "app1",
        "id" : "1",
        "groups" : [
            { "id" : "1", 
              "name" : "test group 1", 
              "desc" : "this is a test group"
             },
            { "id" : "2",
              "name" : "test group 2",
              "desc" : "this is another test group"
             },
              { "id" : "2",
              "name" : "test group 2",
              "desc" : "this is another test group"
             }
        ]              
    }
    ]
   }

 var b,a;
    $.each(myObject.Apps, function() {    
     b = $.grep(this.groups, function(el, i) {
    return el.id.toLowerCase() === "2"                
    });         

   }); 

 alert(JSON.stringify(b));
```

So Once i run this i will get following text in alert as expected.

```
[{"id":"2","name":"test group 2","desc":"this is another test group"},{"id":"2","name":"test group 2","desc":"this is another test group"}]
```

But i want the whole javascript object with this new return array like this.
Expected O/p::

```
 "Apps" : [    
    {
        "Name" : "app1",
        "id" : "1",
        "groups" : [
             { "id" : "2",
              "name" : "test group 2",
              "desc" : "this is another test group"
             },
              { "id" : "2",
              "name" : "test group 2",
              "desc" : "this is another test group"
             }
        ]              
    }
    ]
```

Any idea would be a great help.

Comment: Sure, re-write grep. Can't you just wrap it in the structure you want?

Comment: Copy object, create new object, slice elements out of object, return object.

Comment: Thanks dave. But i am not sure how can i rewrite grep. Can you give me hint? As i am wondering if i will rewrite grep than i might loose previous functionality.

Comment: @ravi I was being sarcastic--what I'm saying is keep `grep` the same, and wrap the results in the structure you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If understand correctly you want to remove any groups not returned in $.grep from the master object.

Using your `$.grep()` method  add one line in the `$.each` loop after `$.grep`

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/67Bbg/

```
var b,a;
$.each(myObject.Apps, function() {    
   b = $.grep(this.groups, function(el, i) {
      return el.id.toLowerCase() === "2"                
   });

  /* replace group with new array from grep */         
   this.groups=b;
 });
```

EDIT: Abbreviated version

```
$.each(myObject.Apps, function() {    
    this.groups= $.grep(this.groups, function(el, i) {
      return el.id.toLowerCase() === "2"                
   });
 });
```

Comment: You don't even need `a` and `b`, just assign the result of `$.grep` to `this.groups`.

Comment: @FábioBatista good point, I just was trying to fill in what I think OP was missing